# Doctrine2 QueryBuilder Join

Tags: php, zend-framework, doctrine-orm

So, I'm new to doctrine, and I'm trying to do a basic joint, but I guess I'm missing something, on my entities or I don't know for sure.

Doctrine Repository:

```
$queryBuilder = $this->createQueryBuilder()
                     ->select('c.*, a.*')
                     ->from('My\Entity\CompanyAdminNotes', 'c')
                     ->innerJoin('Administrators','a','a.id = c.admin_id')
                     ->where('c.admin_id = :admin_id')
                     ->setParameter('admin_id', $id);
return $queryBuilder->getQuery()->getResult();
```

And I get the following error

> Message: [Semantical Error] line 0, col 76 near 'a,
>   My\Entity\CompanyAdminNotes': Error: Identification Variable
>   Administrators used in join path expression but was not defined
>   before.

I'm not sure if my query it's wrong or something else isn't set. Can you guys give me a hint?

Comment: you need to add class/entity name in your join.. i.e. `innerJoin(Entity\Administrators)`

Answer (score 2):

try to change this:

```
->innerJoin('Administrators','a','a.id = c.admin_id')
```

to this:

```
->innerJoin('My\Entity\Administrators','a','a.id = c.admin_id')
```

Because It need the path as you done into the `from`

**UPDATE**

Trying another solution like this:

```
         $queryBuilder = $this->createQueryBuilder('c')
             ->select('c, a')
             ->from('My\Entity\CompanyAdminNotes', 'c')
             ->innerJoin('My:Administrators','a','a.id = c.admin_id')
             ->where('c.admin_id = :admin_id')
             ->setParameter('admin_id', $id);
```

Comment: No, still doesn't work Message: [Semantical Error] line 0, col 85 near 'a, My\Entity\CompanyAdminNotes': Error: Identification Variable My\Entity\Administrator used in join path expression but was not defined before.

Comment: Yes, I have double checked it

Comment: Do I need in my entity to declare some fields as @Join ?

Comment: Ok rememeber to delete the cache that sometimes create errors

Comment: No you don't need to declare some fields as @Join, I think that the problem is semanthical into the query